# Could there be a potential memory leak using Directory.GetDirectories()?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

```
foreach (string path in mainFolders)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            continue;

        Stack<string> pathsToCheck = new Stack<string>(Directory.GetDirectories(path));

        while (pathsToCheck.Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                string cPath = pathsToCheck.Pop();
                string[] dir = Directory.GetDirectories(cPath);

                if (dir.Length > 0)
                    foreach (string s in dir)
                        pathsToCheck.Push(s);
                else
                    folderPaths.Add(cPath.Replace('\\', '/'));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                errors.Add(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is take a list of folder paths and get all of the subdirectories from them. Sometimes this seems to be causing memory usage upwards of 9GB (as said by Task Manager), and while there can be a ton of folders it's checking (most I've checked was 45,000 folders) that's still a relatively small amount of memory.

So is there something wrong I'm not catching that could be leaking that much memory? I'm doing it this way because just Directory.GetDirectories() fails as soon as it comes across a folder that it can't read. I'm using Unity and am stuck with .NET 2.0.

Comment: Don't start with such a conclusion. It will only gain downvotes. Instead, state the problem and *observations* and work a question from there.

Comment: using lots of memory is not bad, using lots of memory and holding on to it (ie other apps starve) is bad. IN fact you want the runtime to use as much in memory as possible.

Comment: @pm100 My game typically uses around 150MB, having it jump to 9GB is quite a problem. Especially when it causes either the game itself or the PC running it to crash.

Comment: Its highly unlikely its a memory leak with GetDirectories, what you are experiencing is just the way the garbage collector works, read through this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals however the rest of your code may be leaking (who knows)

Comment: @Saruman 45,000 folders at 260 characters each would only take up about 22MB. Not really sure how it'd be allocating anywhere near even 100MB.

Comment: Your first point of call is to use a memory profiler, and not task manager. at least then you can work out whats in memory and what shouldn't be, also you could try gc.collect and its finalise method (as a test) to see if its really a garbage collection problem. also, have you factored unicode into this (though it probably want be much of your discrepancy)

Answer (score 1):

A pet peeve of mine is faulty exception handling. And yours can swallow Fatal Exceptions, wich is a deadly sin of exception handling. He are two articles I link often:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

First, you can not do memory measurement with the Task Manager. The values are less the useless: http://www.itwriting.com/dotnetmem.php

Secondly before you try to debug a presumed memory leak, you need to understand how the GC works. In particular that it will try to **avoid** running until application closure if at all possible:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/286d8c7f-87ca-46b9-9608-2b559d7dc79f/garbage-collection-pros-and-limits?forum=csharpgeneral

There are only a few possible Memory Leak scenarios in .NET:

- you add something to a collection, but forget to take it out again later. This memory leak only happens at runtime, as the application closure will still clean everything up
- You are handling unmanaged resoruces and the writer of the class screwed up the [Dispose/Fianlize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx) pattern. Dispose is mandatory. Finalize is a optional thing for use convenience.